# gcc-arm-linux-gnu broke my Fedora 33

Tags: linux, fedora

I just installed the `gcc-arm-linux-gnu` package using `dnf`, and since then (it seems) my entire Fedora installation is broken. `dnf` gives the message

> ImportError ... GLIBCXX_3.4.26 not found (required by /lib64/libdnf.so.2)

I have no idea what I can do to fix this; I cannot use `dnf` anymore to fix packages, nor `yum`.

How could I get this working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the install (probably) added a dir `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` with incompatible libraries. It also registered it with `ld.so.conf`.

Removing the link from `ld.so.conf` and running `ldconfig` fixed it.